# Find the date between 2 dates with business hours + holidays

Tags: date, google-sheets

I need to create a formula to compare two dates, for example:
24-12-2019 18:00 and 28-12-2019 9:00.
Business hours are between 8:00 and 17:30.

In this same field I need also create a time clock.

So I have for example 4 business hours to resolve some problems.
When I create a problem there is 24-12-2019 18:00. (Time after work hours).
The support team start his job after holidays (25th and 26th of December are free). So my deadline time is 28-12-2020 12:00.
And when I don't add a "resolution time" in other field,  the current field should show me a clock (how many minutes/hours left to deadline - 28-12-2019 12:00). The clock should start from 28-12-2019 8:00.

Or maybe someone can create a formula which shows me the date 28-12-2019 ? This is my the biggest problem now.

[1]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgHmq.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft4UQ.png

You can see, that i try to create a few conditions and at the end add them.

There is a problem, when the start hour is between:
a) 17:30-18:30
b) 18:30:01-00:00
c) 00:00 - 8:00
d) 00:00

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Your problem isn't very clear, can you share your sheet? Please break down your problem as concisely as you can, and explain what you have already tried. If you just want to show the date 27-12-2019 you can do that with `=DATE(2019,12,27)`.

Comment: I added a lnks in description. And I made a mistake, the final date should by 28th not 27th of Decemver (because 27th is Sunday)

Answer (score 0):

Getting a date from a datetime is surprisingly easy in Excel: you might know that a date is stored as an integer, while timestamps are numbers between 0 and 1 (but shown as times, obviously). So, if you have a datetime, like "27-12-2020 12:00" and you round this down to the integer value, you should get the date (obviously, if it is shown as a datetime "27-12-2020 00:00", you might need to show it just as a date "27-12-2020").

Comment: I added a 2 screens in description.